# "Loop" through each day in a Pandas Dataframe and extract value from corresponding column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have my pandas dataframe, which is formatted as so.

Date is of the datetime.date type

```
print(dataTime)

Date                 Text             Sentiment
2021-01-28           Some text        1
2021-01-28           Some text        0
2021-01-28           Some text        1
...
2021-03-05           Some text        1
2021-03-05           Some text        1
2021-03-05           Some text        0
```

So the dates are every day from 01-28 to 03-05. I need to isolate each day, get  an average sentiment score from that day, and store it in a list or dataframe. I have tried using the mask, which successfully isolates 1 day, however I can get it to go through every day.

Heres what I have, which correctly gets the first date, but how can I get the score from every day in the dataframe?

```
start_date = datetime.date(2021,1,29)
end_date = datetime.date(2021,1,28)
avgSentimentdf = pd.DataFrame({'avgSentiment'})

mask = (dataTime['Date'] > start_date) & (dataTime['Date'] <= end_date)
dataTime.loc[mask]['Sentiment']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataTime.groupby('Date')['Sentiment'].mean()
```

will create a new Series with average values per each different Date.

You can filter for particular dates before or after.

Comment: Fantastic, that worked! Ive accepted your answer

Comment: @craigco1 Glad it worked. It doesn't show accepted, if you mean to accept it though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and then use an aggregation function to achieve it

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [{"date": "2021-01-28", "text": "Some text", "sentiment": 1},
        {"date": "2021-01-28", "text": "Some text", "sentiment": 0},
        {"date": "2021-01-28", "text": "Some text", "sentiment": 1},
        {"date": "2021-03-05", "text": "Some text", "sentiment": 1},
        {"date": "2021-03-05", "text": "Some text", "sentiment": 1},
        {"date": "2021-03-05", "text": "Some text", "sentiment": 0}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.groupby(["date"])["sentiment"].mean())
```

Output:

```
date
2021-01-28    0.666667
2021-03-05    0.666667
Name: sentiment, dtype: float64
```